# Problems with displaying data in QListView

Tags: qt, qtreeview, qlistview, qstandarditemmodel

Good day!

[image: Screenshot]

There are instances of classes QListView and QTreeView.
Both of the instances loads data from model (QStandardItemModel).
QTreeView displays positions (For example: Chief, Manager, Developer, etc).
Clicking on the title of position a list of employees revealed.

QListView displays only positions of staff.

Question:
How can I display a full list of names of employees in QListView not showing their positions?
Which methods I need to override?
What can you advise in this situation?

P.S. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you are going to be able to do that with a single model.

[This thread](http://lists.qt.nokia.com/pipermail/qt-interest/2011-January/030429.html) suggests using a proxy model to flatten the original one without having to maintain two instances of that data. But the implementation pointed to (KDE's [KReparentingProxyModel](http://api.kde.org/4.5-api/kdepim-apidocs/akonadi/akonadi_next/html/classKReparentingProxyModel.html)) isn't exactly trivial.

There is some documentation on [proxy models](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/model-view-programming.html#using-proxy-models), and the [QSortFilterProxyModel](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/qsortfilterproxymodel.html) might be usable in your context, although I think you'll need something more specific.

You might also find the classes attached to the third response on this thread: [ModelView - how to use proxies to filter this data?](http://groups.google.com/group/qt-mailing-lists-qt-interest/browse_thread/thread/772c5e2280eb1500/10204450e00647ec%3Fq%3D%2522Stephen%2BKelly%2522%2310204450e00647ec&ei=iGwTS6eaOpW8Qpmqic0O&sa=t&ct=res&cd=11&source=groups&usg=AFQjCNHPOoyHOUOxwD6ndcA7Kp0o4wtfRQ) interesting as a starting point.

(Sorry this isn't very specific. Searching for "qt flatten tree model" will give you other ideas.)

Answer (score -2):

Try to use QListWidget, is easier than QListView.

Comment: How can I bind QListWigdet with model?

Comment: You dont use QListWidget when you are working directly with models, and sharing a model between views. QListWidget is for an all-in-one solution to a one-off display.