# QSortFilterProxyModel mapToSource & mapFromSource help needed

Tags: c++, qt

I am implementing Qt Model/View architecture and need little help please.

I have a `QAbstarctItemModel` which is a tree model and serves the `QTreeView` and it works. Now I need to display the same data in `QTableView` for which I need to flatten the tree model. This is where I am lost and need help. I have `QSortFilterProxyModel` to help me. I can't figure out how to override `mapToSource` and `mapFromSource` functions.

This is the same question asked, but no code examples were given.

[QTreeView, QTableView, display items of different hierarchy layers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10531599/qtreeview-qtableview-display-items-of-different-hierarchy-layers)

[Problems with displaying data in QListView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6327322/problems-with-displaying-data-in-qlistview)

Could someone please provide some example code.

Answer (score 0):

I recently answered very similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18128722/convert-qsqlquerymodel-data-into-qvectors/18130955#18130955) with code examples, I hope they will give you an idea where to go.

General rule, think about proxy model as about coordinates transformation, so you have to right a class which will transform coordinates from your source model to destination and other way around..